# Why am I seeing a Cross-thread exception when invoking EventHandler.BeginInvoke through Delegate.Target?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, async-await, invoke

I am attempting to write an extension method which will simplify cross-thread event handling. The below is what I have conceived and by my understanding it should work; however I am getting a cross-thread exception when the EndInvoke method is called...

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SCV {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {

        private static event EventHandler _Test;

        public static event EventHandler Test {
            add { MainWindow._Test += value; }
            remove{ MainWindow._Test -= value; }
        }

        private static async Task OnTest( ) {
            if ( MainWindow._Test != null )
                await MainWindow._Test.ExecuteAsync( null, EventArgs.Empty );
        }

        private LinearGradientBrush brshSomeBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Red, Colors.Black, new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 1));

        public MainWindow( ) {
            InitializeComponent( );
            MainWindow.Test += ( S, E ) => this.Background = this.brshSomeBrush;
                this.Loaded += async ( S, E ) => await MainWindow.OnTest( );
            }
    }

    static class Extensions {
        public static async Task ExecuteAsync( this EventHandler eH, object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            await Task.WhenAll( eH.GetInvocationList( ).Cast<EventHandler>( ).Select( evnt => Task.Run( ( ) => {
                System.Windows.Controls.Control wpfControl;
                System.Windows.Forms.Control formControl;
                Action begin = ( ) => evnt.BeginInvoke( sender, e, IAR => ( ( IAR as AsyncResult ).AsyncDelegate as EventHandler ).EndInvoke( IAR ), null );
                if ( evnt.Target is System.Windows.Controls.Control && !( wpfControl = evnt.Target as System.Windows.Controls.Control ).Dispatcher.CheckAccess( ) )
                    wpfControl.Dispatcher.Invoke( begin );
                else if ( evnt.Target is System.Windows.Forms.Control && ( formControl = evnt.Target as System.Windows.Forms.Control ).InvokeRequired )
                    formControl.Invoke( begin );
                else
                    begin( );
            } ) ) );
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the reason for this to still throw an exception? How am I doing this wrong?

Comment: You got that wrong, a delegate's BeginInvoke() method always runs on a threadpool thread.  Invoke() is good enough.  You also make the hard assumption that the event subscriber is a Winforms or WPF control, major bummer if it turns out to be just a plain class.  You'll only discover that two years from now, very painful.  Don't make it too fancy.

Comment: @Hans Actually, I don't make that assumption. If you look at the If/Else If/Else you will see that the first checks if it's a WPF control, the second checks if it's a WinForms control, and the third assumes it's neither and moves forward. If it's neither of these then the program assumes it's a simple class object... which WILL be a problem if I ever develop in anything that is NOT winforms or wpf (at which point I'll just have to add more links to the if/then chain or figure out a better solution (I do NOT want to write if InvokeRequired into every method; that's why I'm doing it like this.

Comment: Proper way to do it is by using SynchronizationContext.Current.  Lots of Q+A about it.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks; i'll keep that in mind when this starts to fail...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the delegate on the right thread - but the delegate itself then calls `evnt.BeginInvoke`, which executes the `evnt` delegate on the thread pool... so you still end up executing the *real* underlying delegate (in this case `_Test`, will set the background colour) on a non-UI thread.

You've already marshaled to the right thread on which to execute the delegate - so just execute it with `evnt(sender, e)`.